# Can Cordova app development and latex?

Tags: cordova, mobile, latex

I would like to know if there is any way for apps developed in Cordova to bring in latex syntax somehow. Is there a library or a plug-in you can use?

Basically I want to develop a Maths education app that would include lots of formulas and graphs etc.

Thanks a lot.